# Populate a mongoDB using async.series() - MDN Web docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Following the Express Tutorial from MDN web docs, the author creates a mongoDB and seeds it from a separate file.

In that file he/she creates a function that uses async.series to populate different fields, below is the function to create authors and genres

```
function createGenreAuthors(cb) {
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
          authorCreate('Patrick', 'Rothfuss', '1973-06-06', false, callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
          authorCreate('Ben', 'Bova', '1932-11-8', false, callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
          authorCreate('Isaac', 'Asimov', '1920-01-02', '1992-04-06', callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
          authorCreate('Bob', 'Billings', false, false, callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
          authorCreate('Jim', 'Jones', '1971-12-16', false, callback);
        }
        ],
        // optional callback
        cb);
}
```

How would you go about populating a database with thousands of entries using this method, if you had an object containing all the data,

ie,

```
let authors = {
  {dataset1},
  {dataset2},
  ...
  {datasetn}
}
```